# Implement puzzle game on Android

Tags: android, image, opencv, puzzle

I'm familiar with Android Development,

But not with the subject of manipulations on images, etc.

I need to implement a puzzle game:

- Let the user mark and cut a (non symmetric) piece of an image.
- Let the user move and rotate this piece.
- Let the user drag this piece into original place. And so on...

I heard about the [OPENCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) library (also for android). Is it the best option to start with?

I have seen a lot of questions/answers of this issue,

But do android have an official/unoffical library for this issue?

Comment: Were you talking about jigsaw puzzles? Because if you were, did openCV have a solution? Square puzzles is easy, but how to create jigsaw puzzles without using a mask?

Answer (score 1):

One of OpenCV's for Android sample projects is [actually one of those puzzle games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.opencv.samples.puzzle15).

It does not allow the user to cut the pieces and rotate them, but all the rest is there. You have the source code if you download the android package, so it is a great starting point.